# What audio format should I use for Dictaphone iOS app?

Tags: ios, audio-recording, audioformat

I want to make a Dictaphone app for iOS and my preferred audio format is DSS, as I want the recorded file to be of small size.

Is the DSS format supported by iOS? If not, what other format can I use for my app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DSS is not supported by iOS.

The audio technologies in iOS support the following [audio formats](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/miscellaneous/conceptual/iphoneostechoverview/MediaLayer/MediaLayer.html):

- AAC
- Apple Lossless (ALAC)
- A-law
- IMA/ADPCM (IMA4)
- Linear PCM
- µ-law
- DVI/Intel IMA ADPCM
- Microsoft GSM 6.10
- AES3-2003

For information about each of the audio frameworks, see the corresponding entry in [“Media Layer Frameworks.”](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/miscellaneous/conceptual/iphoneostechoverview/MediaLayer/MediaLayer.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007898-CH9-SW3)

Comment: is it possible that I can use any of these audio technology you've mentioned above and then convert the recorded audio file in .DSS format with in my iOS app ?